# Vim Python: better way to call python code?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

```
function! My_dir(fname)
python3 << EOF
import vim
blah = vim.eval('a:fname')
if str(blah) == 'None':
    cb = vim.current.buffer
    cb[0] = ' .vimrc'
    cb.append(' .vim/plugins/')
    cb.append('              newbie.vim')
EOF
endfunction
```

Is there a cleaner way to call python code? Any way to stick common imports in a file, vs doing import vim everytime - within the python block?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `X.py` file and import every thing that you use commonly. For example as I usually need `os` and `sys` libraries in my programs, my `CommonModules.py` is this:

```
import os
import sys
```

Then put this file in a directory and create an Environmental Variable and name it `PYTHONSTARTUP`. and assign the path of that file as its value.

Now every time you open python, the `CommonModules.py` called automatically.

---

How to set environment variables :

Windows Vista and Windows 7 users

From the Desktop, right-click the Computer icon and select Properties. ...

Click the Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab, then click the Environment Variables 
button near the bottom of that tab.

And for linux Users:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables